# SQL case statement then convert to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, int, case-when

I have a field that I want to convert to `int` so I can to a `count`, however some of the field's values are `'null'` so I'm getting an exception when it comes across these

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '_____' to data type int.
```

I thought id be able to do something like the below but I get the same result.

```
CAST( CASE [value] WHEN 'is null' THEN 1 ELSE [value] END AS INT)
```

I want to change all `null` values in [value] to 1 and then change all [value] to `int` so I can calculate this field.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have no issue converting a `NULL` value to an `int`, so I assume the issue is a string `'NULL'`.

SQL Server offers `TRY_CONVERT()`.  I recommend that you use that;

```
select try_convert(int, [value])
```

In other databases, you can use a regular expression to validate the data.

Answer (score 0):

it will be `is null` that is not string

```
CAST( (CASE WHEN [value]  is null THEN 1 ELSE [value] END) AS INT)
```

but its better to use try_convert what actually @Gordon recommend

Comment: I thought that and originally tried that but I get message "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'is'."

Comment: @sql2015 check now

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't actually looking for the `NULL`--which is the absence of data. You have bad data, i.e. the actual text `'NULL'` in a column.

I would actually recommend you updating all the values to `NULL` so you can avoid doing try casting data to fix your problem. That would be something like:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET [value] = NULL
WHERE [value] = 'NULL'
```

Then I would also change the column to a true `INT` type to avoid this in the future. But that's a bit outside the scope of your question.

Of course, you can't always change the data types. If you can, then this will be a more permanent solution.